# Understanding in-place mergesort

Tags: javascript, mergesort

I'm struggling to understand the in-place version of merge sort.

```
function merge(left, right){
    var result  = [],
        il      = 0,
        ir      = 0;

    while (il < left.length &#038;&#038; ir < right.length){
        if (left[il] < right[ir]){
            result.push(left[il++]);
        } else {
            result.push(right[ir++]);
        }
    }

    return result.concat(left.slice(il)).concat(right.slice(ir));
}


function mergeSort(items){

    if (items.length < 2) {
        return items;
    }

    var middle = Math.floor(items.length / 2),
        left    = items.slice(0, middle),
        right   = items.slice(middle),
        params = merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));

    params.unshift(0, items.length);
    items.splice.apply(items, params);
    return items;
}
```

What is the purpose of adding `0` and `items.length` to the front of params? I don't understand what `items.splice.apply` is doing, but from console logging some examples, it looks like it just removes what was unshifted on to `params`. What is the reason for this?

Comment: That's not in-place.

Comment: @user2357112 The code I got this from is https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/10/02/computer-science-and-javascript-merge-sort/. It  says that this is an in-place implementation.

Comment: ...that blog post explains *exactly* what the `unshift` and `splice` stuff does.

Comment: In any case, they're using the term "in-place" wrong. An in-place algorithm uses its input for scratch space, needing at most a small amount of auxiliary storage. It's not just an algorithm that mutates its input instead of returning a new data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: it replaces the contents of `items` with the sorted version.

---

`Array.prototype.splice` has [the following signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

It removes `deleteCount` items starting from index `start` and replaces them with the provided items.

`items.splice.apply(items, params)` executes `items.splice(...)` with the parameters taken from `params`. After `params.unshift(0, items.length)`, `params` is

```
[0, items.length, sortedItem1, sortedItem2, ...]
```

so that call executes `items.splice(0, items.length, sortedItem1, sortedItem2, ...)`, deleting `items.length` items starting from index 0 (so all of them) and replacing them with the items in sorted order.

Comment: could you explain why it's not in-place? I didn't quite get your comment.

Comment: @AlanH: It uses a substantial amount of auxiliary storage for `result`, `slice`, and `concat`.